# Why do I have to call move on an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

In the code below, why doesn't the first call `mkme = mvme_rv` dispatch to `T& operator=(const T&&)`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using T = vector<int>;

int main()
{
  T mvme(10, 1), mkme;
  T&& mvme_rv = move(mvme); // rvalue ref?
  mkme = mvme_rv;           // calls T& operator=(const T&)?
  cout << mvme.empty();     // 0
  mkme = move(mvme_rv);     // calls T& operator=(const T&&)?
  cout << mvme.empty();     // 1
}
```

Comment: The type of `mvme_rv` is rvalue reference to `T`, but when you uses that variable through its name it's nothing more than an lvalue.

Comment: Distinguish "rvalue reference" and "rvalue".

Comment: Naming expressions are always lvlaues. The word "rvalue" in the term "rvalue reference" describes the kind of *reference*: An rvalue reference is a reference that binds to rvalues, and an lvalue reference is a reference that binds to lvalues (mostly). In that sense, rvalue references are a new language feature that adds a generic rvalue-to-lvalue conversion to the language, which didn't exist hitherto.

Comment: `T && t = move(mvme); T && t2 = t; // ERROR!!!` If you can understand why this is wrong, I think you can solve your question on your own.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As skypjack correctly comments, accessing an object through its name always results in an lvalue reference.

This is a safety feature and if you think it through you will realise that you are glad of it.

As you know, `std::move` simply casts an l-value reference to an r-value reference. If we use the returned r-value reference immediately (i.e. un-named) then it remains an r-value reference.

This means that the use of the r-value can only be at the point in the code where `move(x)` is mentioned. From a code-reader's perspective, it's now easy to see where x's state became undefined.

so:

```
 1: auto x = make_x();
 2: auto&& r = std::move(x);
 3: // lots of other stuff
35: // ...
54: // ...
55: take_my_x(r);
```

does not work. If it did, someone maintaining the code would have a hard time seeing (and remembering) that x (defined on line 1) enters an undefined state on line 55 through a reference taken on line 2.

This is a good deal more explicit:

```
 1: auto x = make_x();
 2: //
 3: // lots of other stuff
35: // ...
54: // ...
55: take_my_x(std::move(x));
```

Answer (score -3):

This line of code:

```
mkme = mvme_rv;
```

is a copy and will thus use a copy assignment (`T& operator=(const T&)`). The key thing about this is BOTH objects can be used afterwards and should - if implemented correctly - provide two identical objects.

By contrast, this line of code:

```
mkme = move(mvme_rv);
```

is a move assignment (`T& operator=(const T&&)`). By convention, this will trash the `mvme_rv` object (or at least clear it) and make `mkme` basically what `mvme_rv` was previously.

Effectively `T&&` means a temporary object (aka xvalue) - something that will not last. The `std::move` method basically casts the object to a temporary (credit to @richard-Hodges for that wording). This can then be used in the move assignment method.

So finally to answer you question of why doesn't `mkme = mvme_rv` dispatch to `T& operator=(const T&&)`: it's **because `mvme_rv` isn't a temporary object** (aka xavalue).

---

More about xvalues: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: "std::move operator basically takes a normal object and rips out the guts" No, it doesn't affect the operand. And it isn't an operator.